# Vanishing of path integral over internal d.o.f. of test particle in $SU(N)$ gauge theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, yang-mills, brst

In Ch-2 (Yang-Mills theory) of David Tong’s notes on [gauge theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html). Tong writes an action $$S_w=\int d\tau \hspace{2pt}i w^{\dagger} \frac{dw}{d\tau}+\lambda(w^{\dagger}w-k)+w^{\dagger}A(x^{\mu})w\tag{2.17}$$
Where $A$ is a background field given from YM action, it won’t have any dynamics, $w$ is column vector of $\mathrm{dim}R$ which contains information about “color degree of freedom”, $k$ is a constant and $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier. On page $38$ it is claimed that $$Z_w[A]=\int\mathcal{D}\lambda\mathcal{D}w\mathcal{D}w^{\dagger}e^{iS_w}$$ is **zero** by evaluating path integral over $\lambda$ unless we put an insertion $w_i(\tau=\infty)w_i^{\dagger}(\tau=-\infty)$ in above path integral. I can’t understand how this is happening. I tried discretizing the path integral in $\lambda$ and I got following:
$$\Pi_j\bigg(\int d\lambda_j\hspace{2pt}e^{i\lambda_j(w^{\dagger}w-k)}\bigg)\bigg(…\bigg)$$ the second bracket contains all the remaining part of path integral. How can we deduce first bracket will give us zero? Also there is a gauge symmetry in the action of $S_w$ so I’m not sure if I have to do gauge fixing via BRST procedure to arrive at final conclusion. Tong doesn’t mention BRST during the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

1. The point is that the action (2.17)
   $$S_w\quad\longrightarrow\quad S_w - k\alpha(\infty) + k\alpha(-\infty),$$
   and hence the Boltzmann factor
   $$e^{iS_w}\quad\longrightarrow\quad e^{iS_w}e^{-ik\alpha(\infty)}e^{ik\alpha(-\infty)},$$
   transform under [large $U(1)$ WL gauge transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_gauge_transformation)
   $$ w_i\quad\longrightarrow\quad e^{i\alpha}w_i,$$
   $$ \lambda\quad\longrightarrow\quad \lambda+\dot{\alpha}. $$
   (The path integral measure is invariant/anomaly-free.)
2. The corresponding path integral must therefore sum to zero if the level $k\neq 0$ is non-zero. (Essentially because the sum of over $U(1)$ phase factors is zero.)
3. In contrast the Boltzmann factor at level $k=1$ with 2 two insertions is gauge invariant:
   $$e^{iS_w}w_j(\infty)w^{\dagger}_{\ell}(-\infty)\quad\longrightarrow\quad e^{iS_w}w_j(\infty)w^{\dagger}_{\ell}(-\infty), $$
   and can potentially give a non-zero path integral (especially if $j=\ell$).